# Windows 8.1 Advanced startup options disappeared

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, drivers, refit

OK so a bit of background: I need to disable driver signing because I need to install a modified driver so that I can hook up my PS3 controller.

I have a dual boot setup with Mint 17 and windows 8.1 x64 using rEFInd as the boot manager because MSI hates Linux.

Now I followed [these various steps](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/loading-unsigned-drivers-in-windows-7-and-vista-64-bit-x64/2/) but

1. when I try to get into the advanced startup, it simply does not exist, at all. I have options to shut down or go into uefi, none of the others
2. using *Driver Signature Enforcement Overrider* did nothing, on restart or digitally signing.
3. Tying command line `bcdedit /set TESTSIGNING ON` spews

   ```
   The boot configuration data store could not be opened.  
   The requested system device cannot be found.
   ```

So what I THINK is going on is that it cant find the bcd store, and doesn't store the boot options.

So how do I either

- install an unsigned driver without rebooting
- get into test mode without requiring boot configuration
- set windows boot settings in rEFInd from linux
- sign a driver locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I haven't exactly figure out what happened to the advanced options

But I did solve my problem

1. need a windows 8 DVD
2. boot the dvd and click on repair
3. go to troubleshoot -> advanced options -> command line
4. run `diskpart`

   1. `list disk`
   2. `sel disk 0` select your drive with the efi partition (replace `0`)
   3. `list vol`
   4. `sel vol 1` now select the drive with the efi partition
   5. if it does not have a drive letter, assign one `assign letter=z`
5. And this is the crucial part if you are dual booting. You need to specify where the BCD file manually for `bcdedit` to stop throwing that annoyin error I mentioned

   1. `bcdedit /store z:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD /set {default} loadoptions DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS`
   2. `bcdedit /store z:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD /set {default} TESTSIGNING ON`

For those interested the 2 key parts are specifying your bcd store manually, since in my case the dualbooting screwed things a bit, and specifying `{default}` so that it knows to install it in the **OS loader** not the **Boot manager**

Answer (score 0):

How to Disable Driver Signature Verification on 64-Bit Windows 8.1

- Press the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> keyboard combination to bring up the *Charms Bar*, then click on the *Settings* charm.
- Click on the *Change PC settings* link.
- When the Control Panel opens, switch over to the *Update & recovery* section.
- Click on the *Recovery* option on the left hand side.
- Once selected, you will see an advanced startup section appear on the right hand side. You will need to click on the *Restart now* button.
- Once your computer has rebooted you will need to choose the *Troubleshoot* option.
- *Advanced options*.
- *Startup Settings*.
- Since we are modifying boot time configuration settings, you will need to restart your computer one last time.
- Finally, you will be given a list of startup settings that you can change. The one we are looking for is *Disable driver signature enforcement*. To choose the setting, you will need to press the `F7` key.

[image]

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/)

Comment: that's exactly it. Because the bcd store is missing I do have the advanced options

Comment: do not* have the advanced options